# Acts_as_follower display follows RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using a ruby gem called [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower)

My code:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    acts_as_followable
    acts_as_follower
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def follow
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  current_user.follow(@user)
  redirect_to root_path
end

def unfollow
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  current_user.stop_following(@user)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

**followers.html.erb**

```
<% @user.followers.each do |user| %>

  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
  <br>
    <div class="panel panel-heading">

      <%= avatar_for(user, size: 50) %>
      <h1> <%=link_to user.name, user %></h1>

   </div>
 </div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
#followers
resources :users do
   member do
     get :follow
     get :unfollow
   end
end
```

How to display the users I follow?

Comment: Do you having any problem currently? `@user.followers` seems correct as per the gem.

Comment: Method @user.followers work fine. I want add view with >@user.follows but this method isn't exist in this gem.

Comment: It has `all_follows` try it like `@user.all_follows`

Comment: If it doesn't work, try `@user.all_following`

Comment: @user.all_following works! Thank you!

Comment: Great! I've added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> How to display the users I follow?

I believe the method you want is `all_following`

```
user.all_following
```

> Returns an array of every followed object for the user, this can be a
>   collection of different object types, eg: User, Book

So, the below should work

```
@user.all_following
```